# Selfoss config for NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to config Selfoss with NGINX. I have Selfoss in `/usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss` and I want to access Selfoss on `/selfoss`.
So not on a subdomain.

This is in my NGINX config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /selfoss {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /public/$uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \ (gif|jpg|png) {
            expires 30d;
        }

        location ~ ^/favicons/.*$ {
            try_files $uri /data/$uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/thumbnails/.*$ {
            try_files $uri /data/$uri;
        }

        location ~* ^/(data\/logs|data\/sqlite|config\.ini|\.ht) {
            deny all;
        }

    }
}
```

But the CSS/JS can't be found, and the config.ini is not protected.
How can I have a correct NGINX config for Selfoss.
I also have changed the config.ini to have a base_url of {domain}/selfoss.

**Edit:**

Example of JS resource location:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss/public/js/selfoss-ui.js
```

NGINX error log:

```
2017/04/06 23:00:20 [error] 4413#4413: *25 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: {{client_ip}}, server: localhost, request: "GET /selfoss/all.js?v=1491477650 HTTP/1.1", host: "{{domain}}", referrer: "{{domain}}/selfoss/"
```

Comment: Can you please use curl to request a css/js resource, then edit your question to include the curl command line (hide the domain if you must), access and error logs. Please give us the exact location of the file you curl on your file system as well, ideally showing pwd and ls -l of that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please add the curl that generates that error. You can remove the domain if you have a need to keep it secret.

Comment: I blocked curl, but it would be `curl http://{{domain}}/selfoss/js/selfoss-ui.js`, then I get 403 Forbidden. Is there a other way? Selfoss tries to find js/all.js and css/all.css, css/fonts.css.

Answer (score 0):

**The Information**

```
Root: /usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss;
File: /usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss/public/js/selfoss-ui.js
URL:  /selfoss/js/selfoss-ui.js
```

**Analysis**

Based on the error log and the js resource location I suspect you've set your root incorrectly.

The correct URL for that file, as you've set it up, would be /public/js/selfoss-ui.js

**Solution**

If that URL has to stay as it is, say it's referenced by code you can't change, you have a couple of options:

- Rename the public folder to "selfoss"
- Add a location something like this (I can't guarantee this is correct, but it should give you at least an idea of how to solve it)

Location to add

```
location ~ /selfoss {
  alias /usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss/public;
}
```

The general idea of that location is anything in the URL referring to /selfoss needs to be served from the folder /usr/share/nginx/html/selfoss/public/, but with the selfoss part of the URL not part of the path on the file system. I believe alias is better for this than root - see this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631933/nginx-static-file-serving-confusion-with-root-alias).

Try one of those solutions, but if you try #1 you'll have to revert it before you try #2. The location solution is likely best. If they don't work please edit your question to describe in detail what happened, and demonstrate it using curl and logs.